# Is it possible to push a message to a Dialogflow conversation?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I need to push a message to the end-user after some time of the beginning of the conversation. For example, the end-user starts talking today and subscribes to some kind of event. I would like to send messages from my backend to that conversation after some time without user input between this time.

Comment: How is your user interacting with Dialogflow?

Comment: I am using built-in Telegram integration and my webhook service to handle fulfillment. So if the user types something, I will send a dynamic response from my service. It works fine. But I also want to subscribe the user to my own webhook and send him notification-like messages without any interaction from his side.